# Type [CONTROL] is not defined

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'have a small problem that I can't fix, not very important but embarrassing.

I've a windowsForm app called "MyApp" using a control called "UserControl_Grille" and one day, I've created a folder in my solution to arrange my form and my control. Since this day, when i want to add a control to my form (even a native .NET control) I got this error in my console :

> Type 'MyApp.UserControl_Grille' is not defined

To fix it, i'm going in "MyApp.Designer" in the InitializeComponent Method to find and replace the **"MyApp.UserControl_Grille"** to **"UserControl_Grille"**

But unfortunately each time I add a new control to my form, I have to do this manipulation again.....

Someone have an Idea to fix it once and for all ?
Thanks

Comment: What's the root namespace (properties -> application) of your solution? How do you add the UserControl to your form?

Comment: The root namespace is "myApp", to add my control, i've just drag and drop it to my solution explorer

Comment: Could you try the following two things? 1. Remove your root namespace and check if there's still an issue. 2. Still use a root namespace and add "Namespace MyApp" and "End Namespace" to your usercontrol and check if there's still an issue?

Comment: With your first option, the issue still here. With your second, the issue is gone but I lost all my reference to my Control... There is not an other option to return to the initial state of the project ? Even if I delete my new folder ?

Comment: I haven't done any VB.NET stuff since years just C#. But I expect the issue is that you haven't had a namespace for your usercontrol, and when you drag&drop it, it will be added with the namespace. So I think you've the following two options, add a namespace for every custom control, even in the future, just drag&drop it and do one time overhaul now. Or create your usercontrol by code and do not use drag&drop.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen in a Project where I'd defined a sub-namespace with the same name as my project (root namespace). This happens when you have code that looks like this somewhere in your project:

`Namespace [Name of your Project/Root Namespace]
[...]
End Namespace`

The result of this is that your project contains both a "MyApp" namespace AND a "MyApp.MyApp" namespace (which you can see for yourself if you look at the Object Browser for your project). This situation causes a resolution conflict in the designer file whereby it looks under the wrong namespace for your custom control.

A few possible ways to fix this:

1. Where the sub-namespace is declared (as in the example code above), remove the namespace declaration altogether. This will move all the code within the declaration to your root "MyApp" namespace. You can do this if having that code in a sub-namespace is unnecessary.
2. Where the sub-namespace is declared, right-click the Namespace name and rename it to something OTHER than your Root Namespace's name.
3. If you want to keep the sub-namespace named as such, you can instead rename your root namespace to something unique, from My Project --> Application --> Root namespace.

Option 1 is the simplest option and should immediately resolve the error.

Option 2 is the next simplest, but, for example, if you renamed the sub-namespace to "NewName", all references to "UserControl_Grille" in your Designer files will be mistakenly renamed to "NewName.UserControl_Grille", and you'll have to repair them to "MyApp.UserControl_Grille".

Option 3 is the most tedious, because you have to resolve all Designer file references to the Root namespace, using Find and Replace, being careful not to mistakenly replace legitimate references to the sub-MyApp namespace.